# MongooseError: The MongoDB server disallows overwriting documents using `updateOne`

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I am trying to update a document in MongoDB using mongoose.
I have tried in updateOne() and updateMany() but both of them are giving same error, Apart from Put req , Get, Post, and Delete requests are working fine.

Code:

```
    const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://username:password@generalpurpose.bxoapvc.mongodb.net/wikiDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
});

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

app.put("/articles/:articleTitle", (req, res) => {
    Article.updateOne(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
      { overwrite: true }
    ).then((updated, e) => {
      if (updated) {
        res.send("Article successfully");
      } else {
        res.send(e);
      }
    });
  });
```

The upper code gives the following Error:

```
    /home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3787
      throw new MongooseError('The MongoDB server disallows ' +
            ^

MongooseError: The MongoDB server disallows overwriting documents using `updateOne`. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#update
    at model.Query._updateThunk (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3787:13)
    at model.Query._updateOne (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3881:23)
    at model.Query.exec (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4330:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I changed the code from Article.updateOne() to Article.updateMany() and Article.update() but it is giving the following errors respectively:

Error # 01:

```
/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3787
      throw new MongooseError('The MongoDB server disallows ' +
            ^

MongooseError: The MongoDB server disallows overwriting documents using `updateMany`. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#update
    at model.Query._updateThunk (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3787:13)
    at model.Query._updateMany (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3868:23)
    at model.Query.exec (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4330:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Error # 02:

```
TypeError: Article.update is not a function
    at /home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/app.js:85:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at next (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at next (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at param (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at param (/home/ahmedhassan/wiki-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:376:14)
```

Comment: the error message gives the link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#update try with `replaceOne` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put the overwrite anymore this code will word fine:

```
.put(async (req, res) => {
try {
  await Article.updateOne(
    { title: req.params.articleTitle },
    {
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
    }
  );
  res.send("Article Updated");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}});
```

But, if you still want to have something similar to overwrite, you can use the $set operator:

```
.put(async (req, res) => {
try {
  await Article.updateOne(
    { title: req.params.articleTitle },
    { $set: {
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
    }}
  );
  res.send("Article Updated");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using `updateOne`
You can remove `{ overwrite: true }` and rather use :

```
MyModel.replaceOne(filter, update);
```

Your code would look like this:

```
Article.replaceOne(
  { title: req.params.articleTitle },
  { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Here is the quick solve
[You can check this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK2cN.png)
**You can have have either
replaceOne() method or
findOneAndUpdate. Both are working. Remember to have the 'overwrite' property to be 'true'.**

*Here is the code for your reference*

```
put(function (req, res) {
    article
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          title: req.params.articleTitle,
        },
        { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
        { overwrite: true }
      )
      .then((updatedArticle) => {
        if (updatedArticle) {
          console.log("Document updated successfully!");
        } else {
          console.log("Can't update!");
        }
       res.redirect("/articles");
      })[enter image description here][2]
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```